# valueOf throws NumberFormatException

Tags: java, android

```
System.out.println(etInput.getText().toString());
float myWeight = Float.valueOf(etInput.getText().toString());
```

Hi,

the second line is ment to convert in float a String value (that IS a String because I can print it in console) but I get a NumberFormatException...

some idea about how this can happen?

Stack:

```
08-22 15:03:38.521: E/AndroidRuntime(15341): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-22 15:03:38.521: E/AndroidRuntime(15341): java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
08-22 15:03:38.521: E/AndroidRuntime(15341):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseFloat(FloatingPointParser.java:305)
08-22 15:03:38.521: E/AndroidRuntime(15341):    at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:323)
08-22 15:03:38.521: E/AndroidRuntime(15341):    at java.lang.Float.valueOf(Float.java:362)
08-22 15:03:38.521: E/AndroidRuntime(15341):    at com.mikele.dietmonitor.activity.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:120)
08-22 15:03:38.521: E/AndroidRuntime(15341):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
08-22 15:03:38.521: E/AndroidRuntime(15341):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
08-22 15:03:38.521: E/AndroidRuntime(15341):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-22 15:03:38.521: E/AndroidRuntime(15341):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-22 15:03:38.521: E/AndroidRuntime(15341):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-22 15:03:38.521: E/AndroidRuntime(15341):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
08-22 15:03:38.521: E/AndroidRuntime(15341):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-22 15:03:38.521: E/AndroidRuntime(15341):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-22 15:03:38.521: E/AndroidRuntime(15341):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
08-22 15:03:38.521: E/AndroidRuntime(15341):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
08-22 15:03:38.521: E/AndroidRuntime(15341):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: The String does not contain a float number.

Comment: Show us the String you are trying to convert!

Comment: What does the string look like that you are trying to parse? Does it contain something that should parse into a float value properly?

Comment: i think it is because of Locale ... decimal separator ... in EU we are using `,` and maybe you are getting value with `.` ...

Comment: Just in case and if you're sure you have a String representation of a float: try trimming leading and ending spaces from your string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, simply can't put a call to a method on valueOf(), you have to put a variable.

```
w = etInput.getText().toString();
float myWeight = Float.valueOf(w);
```

Comment: Yes Aleks. Selvin as you can see I only putted this into a variable and it works, they are exactly the same :S I share your wtf :D

Answer (score 2):

The input to method `Float.valueOf` has to be a valid floating point number. So make sure `etInput.getText().toString()` returns a string that contains a valid floting point number i.e. only digits and maximum of one decimal point. One general problem is the trailing spaces, so call trim on `etInput.getText().toString().trim()` to avoid any error due to that.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29):

> If s does not have the form of a FloatValue, then a NumberFormatException is thrown.

Apparently, `etInput.getText().toString()` is not a valid string representation of a float.

Answer (score 0):

The String is not an float-number or it is null.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Float.parseFloat(etInput.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
float myWeight = Float.valueOf(etInput.getText().toString());
```

If you enter a string "a" than it will always throw an error, also I think on empty string too.

Do a

```
try{
    float myWeight = Float.parseFloat(etInput.getText().toString());
catch(NumberFormatException e){
}
```

at least.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
    try {
        Float.parseFloat(etInput.getText().toString());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```